# Performance tune of the following neo4j CQL

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm still beginner to neo4j. Can someone please help me to performance tune the below CQL?

```
WITH apoc.date.parse("2020-04-20",'d',('yyyy-MM-dd')) AS a, apoc.date.parse("2020-04-20",'d',('yyyy-MM-dd')) AS b
MATCH (x:VW_OrderxAttributes_ZSMART_LOTTE)
WHERE a <= apoc.date.parse(x.Zsmart_Lotte_timestamp,'d',('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) <= b
WITH a, b, COLLECT(x.Zsmart_Lotte_OrderID) AS X
MATCH (y:VW_OrderXAttributes_EAI_LOTTE) 
WHERE a <= apoc.date.parse(y.EAI_LOTTE_Timestamp,'d',('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) <= b
WITH X, COLLECT(y.EAI_LOTTE_OrderID) AS Y
UNWIND apoc.coll.disjunction(X,Y) AS XX
RETURN XX;
```

I've created the required indexes needed as well, hoping to improve the performance, but not much improvement.

Below is the PROFILE of the query. I notice that the dbhits is very high.

> +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ | Plan      | Statement   | Version      | Planner | Runtime       |
>   Time | DbHits  | Rows |
>   +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ | "PROFILE" | "READ_ONLY" | "CYPHER 4.0" | "COST"  | "INTERPRETED" |
>   134  | 1458646 | 3238 |
>   +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>
> +--------------------+----------------+--------+---------+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ | Operator           | Estimated Rows | Rows   | DB Hits | Cache H/M |
>   Identifiers | Other
>   |
>   +--------------------+----------------+--------+---------+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ | +ProduceResults    |          13883 |   3238 |       0 |       0/0 |
>   X, XX, Y    |
>   | | |
>   +----------------+--------+---------+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ | +Unwind            |          13883 |   3238 |       1 |       0/0 |
>   X, XX, Y    |
>   ResolvedFunctionInvocation(apoc.coll.disjunction,Some(apoc.coll.disjunction(first
>   :: LIST? OF ANY?, second :: LIST? OF ANY?) :: LIST? OF
>   ANY?),Vector(CoerceTo(Variable(X),List),
>   CoerceTo(Variable(Y),List)))
>   | | |
>   +----------------+--------+---------+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ | +EagerAggregation  |           1388 |      1 |    9088 |       0/0 |
>   X, Y        | X
>   | | |
>   +----------------+--------+---------+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ | +Filter            |        1927380 |   9088 |  476961 |       0/0 |
>   X, a, b, y  | a <=
>   ResolvedFunctionInvocation(apoc.date.parse,Some(apoc.date.parse(time
>   :: STRING?, unit  =  ms :: STRING?, format  =  yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ::
>   STRING?, timezone  =   :: STRING?) ::
>   INTEGER?),Vector(CoerceTo(CachedProperty(y,Variable(y),PropertyKeyName(EAI_LOTTE_Timestamp),NODE_TYPE),String),
>   CoerceTo(Parameter(  AUTOSTRING8,String),String), CoerceTo(Parameter( 
>   AUTOSTRING9,String),String)))
>   | | |
>   +----------------+--------+---------+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ | +Apply             |        1927380 | 158987 |       0 |       0/0 |
>   X, a, b, y  |
>   | | |\
>   +----------------+--------+---------+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ | | +NodeByLabelScan |       21415336 | 158987 |  158988 |       0/0 |
>   X, a, b, y  | :VW_OrderXAttributes_EAI_LOTTE
>   | | |
>   +----------------+--------+---------+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ | +EagerAggregation  |            135 |      1 |    7217 |       0/0 |
>   X, a, b     | a, b
>   | | |
>   +----------------+--------+---------+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ | +Filter            |          18144 |   7217 |  604791 |       0/0 |
>   a, b, x     | a <=
>   ResolvedFunctionInvocation(apoc.date.parse,Some(apoc.date.parse(time
>   :: STRING?, unit  =  ms :: STRING?, format  =  yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ::
>   STRING?, timezone  =   :: STRING?) ::
>   INTEGER?),Vector(CoerceTo(CachedProperty(x,Variable(x),PropertyKeyName(Zsmart_Lotte_timestamp),NODE_TYPE),String),
>   CoerceTo(Parameter(  AUTOSTRING6,String),String), CoerceTo(Parameter( 
>   AUTOSTRING7,String),String)))
>   | | |
>   +----------------+--------+---------+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ | +Apply             |          18144 | 201597 |       0 |       0/0 |
>   a, b, x     |
>   | | |\
>   +----------------+--------+---------+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ | | +NodeByLabelScan |         201597 | 201597 |  201598 |       0/0 |
>   a, b, x     | :VW_OrderxAttributes_ZSMART_LOTTE
>   | | |
>   +----------------+--------+---------+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ | +Projection        |              1 |      1 |       2 |       0/0 |
>   a, b        | {a :
>   ResolvedFunctionInvocation(apoc.date.parse,Some(apoc.date.parse(time
>   :: STRING?, unit  =  ms :: STRING?, format  =  yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ::
>   STRING?, timezone  =   :: STRING?) ::
>   INTEGER?),Vector(CoerceTo(Parameter(  AUTOSTRING0,String),String),
>   CoerceTo(Parameter(  AUTOSTRING1,String),String), CoerceTo(Parameter( 
>   AUTOSTRING2,String),String))), b :
>   ResolvedFunctionInvocation(apoc.date.parse,Some(apoc.date.parse(time
>   :: STRING?, unit  =  ms :: STRING?, format  =  yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ::
>   STRING?, timezone  =   :: STRING?) ::
>   INTEGER?),Vector(CoerceTo(Parameter(  AUTOSTRING3,String),String),
>   CoerceTo(Parameter(  AUTOSTRING4,String),String), CoerceTo(Parameter( 
>   AUTOSTRING5,String),String)))} |
>   +--------------------+----------------+--------+---------+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Comment: `a` and `b` represent the same exact date. Is that intentional?

Comment: @cybersam it may be same or a different date ranges.. it may be either way.